# PHP Array Merge Output 2/array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I have some multimple issues whit this but I never get a good andword about it.

I have some function who respond good but the problmes is is printing x2 my query.

I try to minimize my script to get help fast.

The is about array_merge.

So first

1. Verify Function

```html
function Verify($params) {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT SOMETHING");
    if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
        $row = $query->fetch_assoc();
        // Here will pass 2 array on each function to proceed
        $data = self::CacheData($row['gid'], $params['sid']);
        $data['data'] = self::Host($row['gid'], $params['sid']);
        return $tmpdata;
    }
    return false;
}
```

2. Create ChacheData and Host Function.

```html
static function CacheData($gid, $sid){
    $cachedata = array();
        $querycache = mysql_query("SELECT WHAT I NEED");
        if ($querycache->num_rows == 1) {
            $rowcache = $querycache->fetch_assoc();
            // Send to Files the array and check if is true
            if (self::Files(array('gid' => $gid, 'sid' => $sid, 'expirecache' => 0)) == true) {
                return array('gid' => $gid, 'size' => 0, 'enabled' => $rowcache['enabled'], 'exists' => false);
            }
        }
}

function Host($gid, $sid) {
    $query = mysq_query("SELECT WHAT I NEED");
    if ($query->num_rows == 0) {
            return false;
    }
    $rowgame = $query->fetch_assoc();
    // Send to Files the array and to see if is / false
    if (self::Files(array('gid' => $gid, 'sid' => $sid)) == false) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Ok here is the issues I have

When the Files recive the 2 array it`s working perect but I whant all array send by other function to array_merge all.

So the last function where is the issues is like this

```html
function Files(array $params) {
        $default = array('skipcache' => false, 'expirecache' => 86400, 'os' => null);
        $params = array_merge($default, $params);
        //return $params;
        print_r($params);
}
```

Now The Output will be like

```html
array(5) {
     ["skipcache"]=>
     bool(false)
     ["expirecache"]=>
     string(1) "0"
     ["os"]=>
     NULL
     ["gid"]=>
     string(1) "1"
     ["sid"]=>
     string(1) "1"
}
array(5) {
     ["skipcache"]=>
     bool(false)
     ["expirecache"]=>
     int(86400)
     ["os"]=>
     NULL
     ["gid"]=>
     string(1) "2"
     ["sid"]=>
     string(1) "1"
}
```

Base on this output I add on Database but the problmes is is add 2 on database and I need 1 array not 2.

So I was see the array_merge remove dublicates but here I see all it`s same but Is not remove because $params recive 2 array !

Can you give me some solution but not whit Foreach !

Thank you so much !

Regards,

Comment: But your final array's values are different.. Can you also post your expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$uniqueArr = array_merge(array_flip(array_flip($mergedArray)));
```

or

```
$uniqueArr = array_keys(array_flip($mergedArray));
```

or if you want to use array_unique method:

```
$uniqueArr = array_unique(array_merge($array1,$array2), SORT_REGULAR);
```

from this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php which is much faster than array_unique method. you can array_flip so you get the keys as values and vice versa.

Comment: Still not working. The output do not combine the both array. I just want to print only one array. LIKE   array(5) {
     ["skipcache"]=>
     bool(false)
     ["expirecache"]=>
     int(86400)
     ["os"]=>
     NULL
     ["gid"]=>
     string(1) "2"
     ["sid"]=>
     string(1) "1"
}

Comment: Seems working on me see this fiddle: http://codepad.org/9MPUDCSi, I changed  the `null` and `boolean` values to `empty string` and `0` because it prints a warning that array_flip can only flip values with with string and integer types

Comment: http://codepad.org/yvpi0Gsf ... if you see is output 2 array but I want to output only 1 array if the key is identical

Comment: Hi your using methods in a wrong way. because in that way your calling your method two times in which you are just dumping your array two times, you can use a class so you can store the values in a property and will just use an `empty` method if that property is empty else it will merge the current property to your new property like this: http://codepad.org/qDEL5GNW better if you start using OOP because it's more easier to code in that way. hope this helps.